# Perform search on given site (Jalopnik) using HTTPS/URLLIB and Python

Tags: python, http, https, urllib2, urllib

Just need to know how to use HTTP or urllib (requests) to open Jalopnik, enter a word in its search bar, and 'click' search. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I believe 'clicking' button on that site triggers some `javascript` action, which will not be triggered with `urllib` (it's just not designed to serve this purpose). If you need just to retrieve search results, I'd look into how their search api works and use it.

Anyway, if you really need to emulate 'clicking' search, you could use [Selenium](https://github.com/baijum/selenium-python) to get fully-dynamic site which you'd be able to interact with.